# Ruby code not taking accented letters as inputs, and crashing if "€" is typed

Tags: ruby

I'm having a couple of issues with the most simple code I ever wrote in Ruby.

Let's get straight to the example:

```
# encode: utf-8
`chcp 65001`

puts "Write something with accents such as àòèùì, or €"
asd = gets
puts asd
```

If I run this code I get two issues, and both of them are totally incomprehensible to me at the moment.

The first one is that if I enter something such as `à`, the program will write a new line and not give anything as output. If I press enter again, then it'll output a couple of unreadable characters.

See the pic here as example:

[image: à]

Second issue: if I type `€` the terminal will just crash, even before pressing enter. Of course I can't attach a screenshot for this one.

Note that the terminal does not crash if I type `€` while note executing this program. It only does it if I type it while executing it.

I tried to change the default terminal encoding from CP850 to UTF-8, but that didn't change anything. So now I'm back to CP850, since UTF-8 support in the terminal is beta. And the `chcp 65001` successfully changes the encoding to UTF-8 anyway.

How would you proceed?

EDIT 1:

It appears to me that the `chcp 65001` is successfully chaning the terminal's encoding. In these screenshots, the first one being taken before executing the program and the second being taken after, you'll see that the "Tabella codici corrente", aka "Current code table", has actually changed from CP850 to UTF-8.

[image: pre]
[image: post]

EDIT 2:

This simplified MWE will still give the same result:

```
puts "Write something with accents such as àòèùì, or €"
asd = gets
puts asd
```

Comment: ```chcp 65001``` executes the program `chcp` with the argument 65001. It doesn't affect your program.

Comment: It changes the terminal encoding to UTF-8

Comment: Yes, but not when running it from Ruby like that. ```chcp``` executes in its own process and does not affect the program. See https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-60 Unless I'm misunderstanding something special about how backticks work on Windows. Can you verify that it has changed your code page?

Comment: Code Page 850 has no `€`. Will the terminal display a `€` at all?

Comment: I edited the post with screenshots about this point. Concerning the € character, the terminal will actually type it even before switching encoding, and apparently is able to work with it too since if I type `echo €` it will correct give `€` as output. How is that possible, I don't know.

Comment: "*UTF-8 support in the terminal is beta*" which terminal program are you using? And what version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 10, version 1903. I'm using the default Win10 terminal.

Comment: What version of Ruby, please? And how did you install it?

Comment: The magic comment should be `# encoding: UTF-8`. The case doesn't matter, but `encoding` does. See https://ruby-doc.org/core/Encoding.html#class-Encoding-label-Script+encoding However, UTF-8 should already be the default.

Comment: Ruby is version 2.7.0. I tried writing "encoding" correctly but nothing is changing still

Comment: I tried to change terminal, switching to ConEmu, and I get exactly the same results: weird characters if I enter accented letters, and crash if I type the eur symbol.

Comment: @ilmietitore: The comment is completely irrelevant. First off, it sets the encoding of the *source file*, but your problem is obviously not the encoding of the source file, since the string is printed correctly. Also, UTF-8 is the default anyway, so not only is the comment totally irrelevant to this question, it is also not doing anything.

Comment: In the meanwhile I discovered that EVERY ruby program crashes if a "€" is typed.

Comment: @ilmietitore: There is something seriously wrong with your Ruby installation. A Ruby program should *never* crash. It may do funny things, it may give a wrong result, it may run into an infinite loop, it may raise an exception, it may cause the runtime to raise an exception, but it should *never* crash, unless there is a bug in your Ruby implementation, a bug in your operating system, or a hardware defect in your computer. Also tens of thousands of Ruby programmers all over the world use UTF-8 every day.

Comment: Note that, as was already explained in earlier comments, the first three lines of your original example don't actually do anything, so it it not surprising that the simplified example has the same behavior, since it is the exact same example.

Comment: I just updated it to 2.7.1 though :( Throgh the Ruby installer

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're right that Ruby shouldn't crash. Ruby definitely crashes.